# Hanvon Tablet won't work

Tags: wacom, graphics-tablet

I am trying to use the MYPaint program on a Hanvon Artmaster AM0605 tablet. It won't do anything.  There is a set up for a Wacom tablet. Is there any way to use my Hanvon tablet?

My system is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

All depends if it's recognized by the kernel (i.e., if it has a driver) or not. One way of checking it is the following:

1. open a terminal
2. type `less +F /var/log/syslog` in it. You'll see something similar to the following screenshot.

   [image: syslog shot]

   do not worry about what's there, it depends on lot of things. This is the system messages log.
3. Now connect your tablet. Something should appear at the bottom; for example with mine I have this (I added the highlight after that):

   [image: wacom inserted]

   this means that the kernel found the USB device and detected it is a wacom tablet.
4. to exit and regain control of your terminal, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal, the press <kbd>q</kbd> --- or simply close it, no harm will be done.

Do the same an cut and paste the result in your question.

If nothing happens, or the kernels says that a USB device is connected but it is not detected as a tablet, it means that your  tablet has no driver for Linux --- you need to ask the manufacturer.

Comment: Feb  5 19:22:01 Foxcon kernel: [  698.201617] usb 4-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Feb  5 19:22:01 Foxcon kernel: [  698.201628] usb 4-5: Product: ArtMaster 0605+
Feb  5 19:22:01 Foxcon kernel: [  698.201636] usb 4-5: Manufacturer: Hanvon
Feb  5 19:22:01 Foxcon kernel: [  698.201645] usb 4-5: SerialNumber: V3.0
Feb  5 19:22:01 Foxcon mtp-probe: checking bus 4, device 10: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb4/4-5"
Feb  5 19:22:01 Foxcon mtp-probe: bus: 4, device: 10 was not an MTP device
No help from Hanvon.It just wont work.

Comment: So the kernel noticed that you have a USB devices, but it can't say it is a tablet. No driver for it; you should check with the manufacturer.

Comment: I found some information on the "make" comand but I think that is out of my Ubuntu depth.  Maybe someone could make one for me?

Comment: @dallasboothe, `make` is a generic command to build (compile from source) programs, kernels, drivers. But you need the source code of the driver to use it --- and for writing a driver you must know very well your tablet hardware, the interface with the PC, the linux kernel, and be a quite good programmer. The manufacturer of the tablet will have the info and the skill --- but I do not know if they want to support linux.

Answer (score 0):

I use a Hanvon Armaster with the drivers based on the hanwang.c driver (Hanvon is a subsidiary of Hanwang) from https://github.com/ondrah/hanvon.  or http://linux.fjfi.cvut.cz/~taxman/hw/hanvon/

Sadly these seem to be unsupported now and becoming unreliable in recent Ubuntu releases, to the point where they are no longer working at all on a clean installation of Ubuntu 17.04. see https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2333186&p=13569455#post13569455